# Randomising with adjacency constraints

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, combinatorial-designs, latin-square

I am a high school political science teacher looking for some help in implementing a classroom exercise. It's a puzzle of sorts, I suppose. I've tried Googling the issue for a while, but my GoogleFu is simply not good enough to get me the solution I need. I apologise if I'm unclear in my description below.

I want my class of 9 students to create a chain of arguments that respond to the previous one in the chain. I would like each student to be working in parallel, so there will be 9 chains being built simultaneously. I visualise it as a 9x9 table, with the columns being the themes of the argument chains and the rows being the responses.

I would like to generate an order in which my students will be responding to arguments such that:

1) Each student is represented only once in each 'row' (responses).

2) Each student is represented only once in each 'column' (chain).

3) No student responds to the same student more than once, that is, in the vertical order of the columns, student X does not succeed Y in more than one column.

I'm happy to be directed elsewhere if my question is not appropriate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it matter if the same student appears multiple times in the same chain? I.e. might it be possible to go 1-2-3-1-4-3-2-1-8, for example?

Comment: Does each student appear exactly once in each chain?

Comment: Yes, each student should be in each chain only once. Apologies for not having clarified this. I will edit the post.

Comment: Just to phrase this in a way combinatorialists can easily understand: does there exist a 9x9 Latin square $a_{i,j}$ such that the 72 ordered pairs of the form $(a_{i,j},a_{i+1,j})$ are all distinct?

Comment: Thanks, Max! I had no idea which discipline my question would be relevant to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! Here's how:

[image]

I found this example in *Some New Row Complete Latin Squares* by D.S Archdeacon, J.HDinitz and D.RStinson, see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316580900400

Comment: There remains the issue of vertical succesive pairs.

In the square you've posted, for example, 7 is succeeded by 8 in both column 7 and 8, and 2 is succeeded by 3 in columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 8.

Comment: Oops, in my matrix, the rows are the chains, not the columns. @Superchaddi

Comment: Hey, that works! 

I haven't quite grasped the method mentioned in Archdeacon et al, though. Do you know of a more layman friendly explanation? I intend to use this exercise in a number of classes, so will need to be self-sufficient in generating the order from now on.

I've looked up and understood the method for an even-numbered squared, but it would seem that odd numbers are a challenge.

Comment: @Superchaddi, the method given ("*Using a backtracking algorithm*") basically means "Writing a computer program to try all possibilities".

Comment: @Superchaddi I'm afraid I don't. It's a hard open problem. Perhaps you should give up on perfection, and instead try to find a schedule which has a small number of column-pair repetitions.